# Getting array key value in nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, oop, pdo

I need to get an array value with the key name being `"name"` but I can’t seem to figure it out. I am displaying an error when a user doesn’t fill out a field and I want it to be more specific. In my case when I output an error the page says `fname needs to be filled` but in an array in my script that checks the required things in a form I listed a name and I want it to display `First Name needs to be filled`. My code is below.

```
<?php
require_once 'Assets/Scripts/Core/Init.php';

if(Input::exists()){
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){
        $Validate = new Validate();
        $Validation = $Validate->check($_POST, array(
            'fname' => array(
                'name' => 'First Name',
                'required' => true,
                'min' => '2',
                'max' => '16',
                'alpha' => true
            ),
            'lname' => array(
                'name' => 'Last Name',
                'required' => true,
                'min' => '2',
                'max' => '16',
                'alpha' => true
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'name' => 'E-Mail',
                'required' => true,
                'max' => '128',
                'email' => true,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'name' => 'Password',
                'required' => true
            ),
            'pn' => array(
                'name' => 'Phone Number',
                'required' => true,
                'max' => '10',
                'num' => true
            ),
            'student_id' => array(
                'name' => 'School ID',
                'required' => true,
                'max' => '10',
                'num' => true
            )
        ));

        if($Validate->passed()){
            $user = new User();
            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {
                $user->create('users', array(
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'fname' => Input::get('fname'),
                    'lname' => Input::get('lname'),
                    'phone' => Input::get('pn'),
                    'student_id' => Input::get('student_id'),
                    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                    'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'usergroup' => 1
                ));
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            echo print_r($Validate->errors());
        }
    }
}
```

**My validation class:**

```
<?php
class Validate {
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function check($data, $items = array()){
        foreach($items as $item => $rules){
            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){
                trim($value = $data[$item]);
                $item = escape($item);

                if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)){
                    $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                }
                else if(!empty($value)){
                    switch($rule){
                        case 'min':
                            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value){
                                $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'max':
                            if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
                                $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'matches':
                            if($value != $data[$rule_value]){
                                $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'unique':
                            $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                            if($check->count()){
                                $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'email':
                            if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                $this->addError("{$item} is not a valid email.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'num':
                            if(!is_numeric($value)){
                                $this->addError("{$item} can only contain numbers.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'alpha':
                            if(!ctype_alpha($value))
                            {
                                $this->addError("{$item} can only contain letters.");
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)){
            $this->_passed = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function addError($error){
        $this->_errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function errors(){
        return $this->_errors;
    }

    public function passed(){
        return $this->_passed;
    }
}
```

**Input class:**

```
<?php
class Input {
    public static function exists($type = 'post'){
        switch($type) {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
            break;
            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    public static function get($item){
        if(isset($_POST[$item])){
            return $_POST[$item];
        }
        elseif(isset($_GET[$item])){
            return $_GET[$item];
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to output the value that has the key `'name'` in the `fname` array. In this case it should output `First Name`.

Comment: considering you're using a ton of magic functions here and haven't bothered to show us the source to those.... no, we can't help you.

Comment: YOu should post your `get` method

Comment: @Tularis its a lot of classes but you dont need them to get the value of this. I would think you would use a foreach loop to get to the value but im not exactly sure the correct way.

Comment: @EmilioGort i posted my validation class

Comment: You even need a loop to get this values

Comment: I'm sure it's a lot of classes. But you're validating using some kind of "Validate"-class that I don't know. Inside that you probably want to find the missing parts. We don't know what your class even remotely looks like, so can't really help there.

Comment: `Input::get` this is what get the value, i cant see it

Comment: In your validation class move the 'required' check up to BEFORE that loop (so between the two loops), then check for $item['required'] and the non-empty part. If empty/non-existant, add the error message, but instead of referring to  $this->addError("{$item} is required"); change it to  $this->addError("{$rules['name']} is required");

Comment: @Tularis can you create an answer im not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change $item to $rules['name']

```
public function check($data, $items = array()){
    foreach($items as $item => $rules){
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){
            trim($value = $data[$item]);
            $item = escape($item);

            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)){
                $this->addError("{$rules['name']} is required");
            }
            else if(!empty($value)){
                switch($rule){
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value){
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $data[$rule_value]){
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                        if($check->count()){
                            $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'email':
                        if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} is not a valid email.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'num':
                        if(!is_numeric($value)){
                            $this->addError("{$item} can only contain numbers.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'alpha':
                        if(!ctype_alpha($value))
                        {
                            $this->addError("{$item} can only contain letters.");
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your `"is required"` section out of the `rules` loop so you can actually use it easily. Then you can also reference the `"pretty"` name easily.

Simply change your `Validate::check` function to:

```
public function check($data, $items = array()){
    foreach($items as $item => $rules){
        // check required earlier (moved to here)
        if(isset($rules['required']) && $rules['required'] && empty($data[$item])) {
           $this->addError($rules['name'] . " is required");
        }
```

Please note that I changed it to use `$rules['name']` instead of `$item` so you get the `"pretty"` name.

```
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){
            trim($value = $data[$item]);
            $item = escape($item);

            // removed the required check here

            else if(!empty($value)){
                switch($rule){
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value){
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $data[$rule_value]){
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                        if($check->count()){
                            $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'email':
                        if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} is not a valid email.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'num':
                        if(!is_numeric($value)){
                            $this->addError("{$item} can only contain numbers.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'alpha':
                        if(!ctype_alpha($value))
                        {
                            $this->addError("{$item} can only contain letters.");
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but moving the if statement did nothing and i saw you changes $item tp $rules['name'] when i switched the 2 i got what i was looking for.